# Why re-defining a TOC title font does not work in tocloft package?

Tags: memoir, tocloft

I tried to use `tocloft` package to redefine the TOC title font as suggested in its documentation section 2.2 on p. 7

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Huge}% Error on this line
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{title}
\section{title}
\end{document}
```

That throws the error

> Command \cfttoctitlefont undefined. \renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}

Comment: `tocloft` should not be used with `memoir`, `memoir` has its own version of `tocloft` build in and some of the macros have slightly different names

Comment: I added the `memoir` tag as it is important in this case.

Answer (score 3):

`tocloft` should not be used with `memoir` it has its own setup (similar to `tocloft` but not identically.

In `memoir` we defined the TOC header to use the same macro that `\chapter` uses to typeset the title (to ensure a coherent design)

To do what you are attempting, you can use

```
\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\Huge #1}%
```

The default is running `\printchaptertitle` which in its default state is just `\chaptitlefont #1`

Comment: That was my question from someone else's machine and you had put me in the right direction. Indeed `memoir` does a whole lot, but it is unfortunate that there are major inconsistencies in the macro naming while at the same time there is no clear indication that `tocloft` is not even loading under `memoir`.